# How do I set a default printer in an eclipse rcp product

Tags: eclipse, printing, default, rcp

I have an eclipse RCP product and would like to set the default printer. I haven't had any luck googling this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

RCP doesn't have printing layer so it delegate setting default printer to the printer driver. Java only use the printer driver to set a printer as default. So it is impossible to set default printer in RCP layer.

If you want to print something, java AWT support it.
see this:

```
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class PrinterSetup 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pf = pjob.defaultPage();
        pjob.setPrintable(null, pf);

        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
          pjob.print();
        }
    }
}
```

You can set default printer here if your printer driver support it.